# Devise reset password integration test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, integration-testing

Hi I wrote an integration test for the Devise reset password recovery. I have an issue with reset_password_token, which is always invalid, but it should be fine because User with this token does exist.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my test:

```
should "reset his password" do 
  visit "/"
  click_link "Login"

  assert page.has_content?("Log in")

  click_link "Forgot your password?"

  assert page.has_content?("Forgot your password?")
  fill_in 'user[email]', with: @user.email

  assert_difference "ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size", 1 do
    click_button "Send me reset password instructions"
    assert @user.reload.reset_password_token.present?
  end
  assert page.has_content?("You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password in a few minutes.")

  visit edit_user_password_path(reset_password_token: @user.reset_password_token)
  fill_in 'user[password]', with: 'newpassword'
  fill_in 'user[password_confirmation]', with: 'newpassword'
  click_button "Change my password"

  assert page.has_content?("Your password has been changed successfully. You are now signed in.")
end
end
```

And this is the mail view:

```
%p
Hello #{@resource.email}!
%p Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link   
below.
%p= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token:   
@token)
%p If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.
%p Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your mail view, Change:

```
edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token:   
@token)
```

To :

```
edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.password_reset_token)
```

Comment: No, sorry. Still the same :/ Reset password flow does work when I do it manually, but test does always fail :/

Answer (score 0):

This documentation should help you:

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable

Look at the method: send_reset_password_instructions it calls the set_reset_password_token, which should be available in the @user instance.